# Collect with linear combinations

Tags: expression-manipulation

Is there a way to collect coefficients on specific linear combinations of variables? Consider the example below:

```
expression = a x1 + (b^2)/3 y1 + z1 - a x2 - (b^2)/3 y2
```

I would like to output the collected coefficients on the linear combinations `(x1 - x2)` and `(y1 - y2)`, that is

```
a (x1 - x2) + (b^2)/3 (y1 - y2) + z1
```

Thanks.

Comment: To literally `Collect` use a temporary change of variables: `Collect[expression /. {x1 -> v1 + x2, y1 -> v2 + y2}, {v1, 
   v2}] /. {v1 -> x1 - x2, v2 -> y1 - y2}`

Comment: Yes, this works indeed, very simple and elegant solution. Would be happy to vote it as an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
expression = a x1 + (b^2)/3 y1 + z1 - a x2 - (b^2)/3 y2;
```

To literally [`Collect`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect.html), use a temporary change of variables :

```
Collect[expression /. {x1 -> v1 + x2, y1 -> v2 + y2},
  {v1, v2}] /. {v1 -> x1 - x2, v2 -> y1 - y2}

(* a (x1 - x2) + 1/3 b^2 (y1 - y2) + z1 *)
```

Comment: As a quick follow-up, is there a way to prevent mathematica from doing any simplification at all in the output? For example, naturally mathematica will simplify x - x to 0.

Comment: If you use `HoldForm`, `HoldPattern`, or similar then no simplifications will be made; however, you also cannot manipulate the expression in any fashion.

Answer (score 4):

```
FullSimplify[expression]
```

> ```
>  a (x1 - x2) + 1/3 b^2 (y1 - y2) + z1
> ```